# Proper way to check if a folder exists in AWS S3 from AWS EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Before calling this a duplicate, please read my question.

I have found two methods of checking if a folder exists in S3 *from EMR* but I wonder which one is correct. To get the credentials of the EMR (eg. from a Spark application) machine to access S3, I did: `new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials`.

1. Use `AmazonS3.doesObjectExist(s3Bucket, s3Prefix)`

   - `s3.doesObjectExist("my-bucket", "my-directory")` returns false but it is true
   - `s3.doesObjectExist("my-bucket", "my-directory/")` returns true
   - `s3.doesObjectExist("my-bucket", "my-directory2")` returns false but it is true
   - `s3.doesObjectExist("my-bucket", "my-directory2/")` returns false but it is true
2. In the mean time, here is my fix:
   `s3.get.listObjectsV2(s3_bucket, s3_object).getKeyCount > 0`. You don't need to fetch all the results matching this request but only the first window, checking it is not empty.

**Why does (1) return false when (2) return true? Which solution do you advise?**

Answer (score 2):

For now, I would suggest to stick with 2 or upgrade the library version. As you are working with EMR stack, it may not be possible to do it without running into conflicts.

There have been [issues](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/295) reported previously with `doesObjectExist`.